# Text mining R seperate text into columns

Tags: r

I am doing a project in r and am analyzing text.  I have strings of the form

```
 "id": 8784, "name": "Daniel", "age":"65", "gender":"M"
```

and things of this sort.  My question is how I can get the data so that each variable can become its own column, that is a name column, with the first entry being Daniel.

Comment: As i look at the data I realized I made a mistake, it is actually of this form "[{\"cast_id\": 242, \"character\": \"Jake Sully\", ... }]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would be to use the `JSON` route

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
sprintf("{%s}", str1) %>%
   fromJSON %>% 
   as.data.frame
#    id   name age gender
#1 8784 Daniel  65      M
```

If there are multiple strings, we can use

```
sprintf("{%s}", str1) %>% 
            map_df(fromJSON)
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments, if it also have `[{..}]`

```
str1 <- '[{"id": 8784, "name": "Daniel", "age":"65", "gender":"M"}]'
fromJSON(str1)
#    id   name age gender
#1 8784 Daniel  65      M
```

For multiple elements,

```
str1 <- c(str1, str1)
str1 %>% 
     map_df(fromJSON)
#    id   name age gender
#1 8784 Daniel  65      M
#2 8784 Daniel  65      M
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '"id": 8784, "name": "Daniel", "age":"65", "gender":"M"'
```

Comment: so, i neglected to mention this, but the str1 was a sample from a data set.  I should have been more clear, the data has [{ }] closing all the data and is therefore not in string form

Comment: Error: parse error: invalid object key (must be a string)
                                      {[{"cast_id": 242, "character": 
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: @pythonbeginner  If u didn't mention all of these things, then how do others know.  I can only process the data based on what you showed in the post.  Please use `dput` to show the example so that the structure is correct.  If it is not in string format, then what is the class of that

Comment: @pythonbeginner  If the data is `str1 <- '[{"id": 8784, "name": "Daniel", "age":"65", "gender":"M"}]; fromJSON(str1)#
    id   name age gender
1 8784 Daniel  65      M`

Comment: its a character structure

Comment: @pythonbeginner  With the structure you mentioned, it is directly converting to `data.frame` with `fromJSON`.  WIth a vector of more than 1 element, you can use `str1 %>% map_df(fromJSON)`

Comment: so ive realized the issue, its a list with all the elements repeating and seperated by {}. That is, we'd have     [{"id": 8784, "name": "Daniel", "age":"65", "gender":"M"} ,   {"id": 8785, "name": "Jim", "age":"69", "gender":"M"}]  etc.